# Add Javascript objects using HTML forms

Tags: javascript

So i am new to javascript but looking for a way to create objects from form data received from html for example

```
var Person = function(dateOfBirth,firstName,lastName){
     this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
  }

var john = new Person(1996,John,Smith);
```

Now i want a user to as a example add him self as object using a form in the front end . is there any trick to perform this type of task.

if there is a answer to this i have missed feel free to just send me a link but as far as a could see there was none

Comment: On form submit just get the values and use them to create a new Person object? Although don't really see the point in having a class definition.

Comment: Study some tutorials on getting and setting values of form control elements like `<input>` , `<select>`, `<textarea>` etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="post" id="foo">
        <div><input type="text" name="bar_1"></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="bar_2"></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="bar_3"></div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>

function Person(dateOfBirth, name, age) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

    var dateOfBirth = document.getElementById('bar_1').value;
    var name = document.getElementById("bar_2").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("bar_3").value;

    var John = new Person(dateOfBirth, name, age);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this. Simple Example.

```js
var Person = function(dateOfBirth,firstName,lastName){
     this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
     this.firstName = firstName;
     this.lastName = lastName;
  }

function createPerson()
{
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  var dateOfBirth = document.getElementById("dateOfBirth").value;
  
  var person =  new Person(dateOfBirth, firstName, lastName);
  
  console.log(person);
}

//var john = new Person(1996,John,Smith);
```

```html
<form>
First Name: <input type="text" id="firstName" /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastName" /><br />
Date of Birth: <input type="text" id="dateOfBirth" /><br />

<input type="button" onclick="createPerson()" value = "Add Person" />
</form>
```